# can we add EKS windows Worker nodes?

Tags: amazon-eks

We are doing POC where, we have existing DEV and PROD ready AWS EKS cluster 1.19, especially running using AWS CNI plugin v1.7 and on linux platform. Question - before we spend time and researching, possible to add EKS Worker nodes (windows platform) to existing AWS EKS cluster or should we have seperate EKS Cluster for Windows only nodes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the documentation on this is pretty clear. For example here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/windows-support.html

So it seems that:

- You indeed can add windows nodes to an EKS cluster. They will be configurated in a separate **nodegroup** inside your EKS **cluster**.
- You should always have at least one Linux node in your EKS cluster (so that would be in a separate node group) to run core EKS services.

  > Amazon EKS clusters must contain one or more Linux nodes to run core system pods that only run on Linux, such as coredns and the VPC resource controller.